# compiler suggests two candidates for class

Tags: c++, c++98

I am learning c++98 and I get this error while compiling my Node class:

```
Node.cpp:13:1: error: no declaration matches ‘Node::Node(Node::dataType&)’
   13 | Node::Node(dataType& initData){
      | ^~~~
In file included from Node.cpp:7:
node.h:13:7: note: candidates are: ‘Node::Node(const Node&)’
   13 | class Node{
      |       ^~~~
node.h:19:5: note:                 ‘Node::Node(const dataType&)’
   19 |     Node(const dataType&);
      |     ^~~~
node.h:13:7: note: ‘class Node’ defined here
   13 | class Node{
      |       ^~~~
```

This is my Node.cpp

```cpp
#include "node.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


Node::Node(dataType& initData){
  data = initData;
  next = NULL;
  prev = NULL;
}

void Node::setData(dataType& newData){
  data = newData;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* nextLink){
  next = nextLink;
}

void Node::setPrev(Node* prevLink){
  prev = prevLink;
}

dataType Node::getData(){
  return data;
}

Node* Node::getPrev(){
  return prev;
}

Node* Node::getNext(){
  return next;
}
```

This is my Node.h

```cpp
#ifndef TYLER_NODE
#define TYLER_NODE

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "EToll.h"

class Node{
  public:
    //TYPEDEF
    typedef EToll dataType;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    Node(const dataType&);


    void setData(const dataType&);
    void setNext(Node*);
    void setPrev(Node*);

    dataType getData() const;
    const Node* getPrev() const;
    Node* getPrev();
    const Node* getNext() const;
    Node* getNext();

  private:
    dataType data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};
#endif
```

It's supposed to be a simple class that holds instances of EToll (from EToll.h) for use in a linked list but I get this error. It looks like the compiler is mistaking the Node class for the Node constructor but I'm still learning so I'm not too sure

Comment: The error explains it all: in your class definition you've only delcared one contructor whose signature is `Node(const dataType&)`, yet you define a whole other constructor that doesn't exist in your `.cpp` file (its signature is `Node::Node(dataType&)`) (You have a similar issue with `setData` btw).

Comment: By the way, you could probably remove a lot of the code in your examples and still reproduce the error. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why don't you learn C++20 instead of C++98?

Comment: @Antonio This uni class is on data structures and the course coordinator said we have to for all of our assignments. I think it's stupid as well, if we need to learn the language we may as well learn the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion here stems from the compiler’s **thoroughness** in reporting the candidates.  The first is the **implicitly** declared copy constructor, which refers spatially to the class name because, well, it’s implicit.  That’s not very helpful to see here because you can’t define an implicitly declared function anyway, but that check comes **after** “Did you match any constructor at all?”, which you didn’t because of the `const`.